# Scipy odeint. Gravitational motion

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, numerical-integration

I solve the motion in gravitational field around the sun with scipy and mathplotlib and have a problem. My solution is not correct. It is not like in

example:

[image: example].

Formulas:

[image: Formulas] that I used.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import scipy.constants as constants
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M = 1.989 * (10 ** 30)
G = constants.G
alpha = 30
alpha0 = (alpha / 180) * np.pi
v00 = 0.7
v0 = v00 * 1000


def dqdt(q, t):
    x = q[0]
    y = q[2]
    ax = - G * M * (x / ((x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 1.5))
    ay = - G * M * (y / ((x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 1.5))
    return [q[1], ax, q[3], ay]


vx0 = v0 * np.cos(alpha0)
vy0 = v0 * np.sin(alpha0)
x0 = -150 * (10 ** 11)
y0 = 0 * (10 ** 11)
q0 = [x0, vx0, y0, vy0]

N = 1000000
t = np.linspace(0.0, 100000000000.0, N)

pos = odeint(dqdt, q0, t)

x1 = pos[:, 0]
y1 = pos[:, 2]

plt.plot(x1, y1, 0, 0, 'ro')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?
Maybe you can tell me solution with another method for example with Euler's formula or with using other library.
I will be very greatful if you help me.

Comment: Consider providing the option `Dfun=...` inside `odeint((...)`. It is the gradient (Jacobian) of function `dqdt` you already have.

Comment: Can you explain a little better what we need to do, please?